# Oracle: insert on an updatable view

Tags: oracle, view

Is it possible to use a view to modify one or more tables in join? How?

Comment: can you be a bit more descriptive?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is, but there are limitations and caveats. Generally, only the `many` table of a `one to many` relationship can be updated.

You should read on "key preserved" in the oracle docs.
[This question](http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11%3a%3a%3a%3a%3aP11_QUESTION_ID:548422757486) on Ask Tom gives a peek on the world of updatable views.

Personally, I have stayed away from updating views.